# Send data with Ajax to the controller in asp core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I want to send the information of a user and his roles to the controller. The user information is sent but the roles are not sent.
Each user can have several roles
please guide me

```
var postData = new FormData();
        postData.append('FullName', $("#fullname").val());
        postData.append('Email', $("#email").val());
        postData.append('MobileNumber', $("#number").val());
        postData.append('NationalNumber', $("#national").val());
        postData.append('Password', $("#password").val());
        postData.append('RePassword', $("#rePassword").val());

        var arr = { Id: '1' };
        postData.append('roles', arr);

        $.ajax({
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            dataType:"JSON",
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Admin/Users/AddUser",
            data:postData,
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.isSuccess == true) {
                    swal.fire('موفق!', data.message, 'success')
                        .then(function (isConfirm) { window.location.reload(); });
                }
                else {
                    swal.fire('هشدار !!', data.message, 'warning');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code as follows.

```
 var arr = { Id: '1' };
 postData.append('roles[0].Id', arr.Id);
```

Test result:
[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful,can you [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck for a few days, but this issue was resolved

Comment: Glad can help you :)